# Rendering to React from reducers

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reducers

Good evening. I have some problems with rendering elements from array.
I need to show this element on page **Component List** - *img alt="job" src={image.img}*, but now my console shows error to me and I think it is problem inside *.map*.
All sources connect with reducer.

**Component List**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AlbumsShow extends Component {

   renderImage(){
        return this.props.images.map((id, image) => {
            return(
                <li key={image.id}>                 
                        <img alt="job" src={image.img} />
                        <p className="album_titulo">Test</p>
                </li>
            );
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (

            <div>                
                {this.renderImage()}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        images: state.image
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumsShow);
```

**Component Layout**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';


class AlbumLayout extends Component {
        handleClick(album){
            browserHistory.push({
                pathname: "album/" + album.id,
                state: {albumDetails: album}
            });
    }

    renderList(){

        return this.props.albums.map((album) => {
            return(

                <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, album)} key={album.id}>                 
                        <img alt="job" src={album.img} />
                        <p className="album_titulo">{album.title}</p>
                </li>

            );
        });
    }


    render(){

        return (

            <div>
                <div className="albums">
                    <div className="albums_caixa">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <ul className="no_pad">
                                    {this.renderList()}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){

    return {

        albums: state.album

    };
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumLayout);
```

**Reducer**

```
export default function() {

    return [

        { id: 1, 
         title: 'Album First',  
         img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg',
         images: [      
                    { id: 1, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'},
                    { id: 2, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'},
                    { id: 3, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'},
                    { id: 4, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'},
                    { id: 5, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ac/53/81/ac538106cc0430926af9b1fbcc761f04.jpg'},
                    { id: 6, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'},
                    { id: 7, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ac/53/81/ac538106cc0430926af9b1fbcc761f04.jpg'},
                    { id: 8, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'},
                    { id: 9, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ac/53/81/ac538106cc0430926af9b1fbcc761f04.jpg'},
                    { id: 10, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'},
                    { id: 11, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ac/53/81/ac538106cc0430926af9b1fbcc761f04.jpg'},
                    { id: 12, img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'}
         ]
    },
        { id: 2, title: 'Album Second', img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'},
        { id: 3, title: 'Album Second', img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'}

    ];

}
```

I will really appreciate for any help!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @AndrewLi, Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Comment: Have you tried logging state inside `mapStateToProps` to verify it's being mapped to props properly? Also, your `map` seems off. The first argument of the callback is the image, the second is the current index.

Comment: @AndrewLi, I add "Component Layout" to my question. In this component map work :(

Comment: I think you need to add this to a constructor: this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this)

Comment: @Sage, unfortunately, it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply have a typo, in your state you have `images` but then you access `state.image` inside the component which does not exist.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AlbumsShow extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.renderImage = this.renderImage.bind(this);
   }

   renderImage(){
        return this.props.images.map(image => {
            return(
                <li key={image.id}>                 
                  <img alt="job" src={image.img} />
                  <p className="album_titulo">Test</p>
                </li>
            );
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
          <div>{this.renderImage()}</div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
      // images: state.image WRONG
      // images: state.images WRONG WITH THE UPDATED STATE
     images: state.albums[0].images
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumsShow);
```

Furthermore you were using the params of map incorrectly, I also made that correction in the snippet.

I just noticed a few errors on your state, here we have an array but then you access it in the component like an object, I will simplify for clarity. There are a few problems here, this state has a confusing structure, some albums have images some have not, so you won't be able to access images for those albums, in your component you are trying to access a field of an array, which is `undefined`. You should clear your mind on how you want to structure your state.

```
export default function() {

    return [
     { id: 1, 
       title: 'Album First',  
       img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg',
       images: [      
         { id: 1, img: 'someUrl'},
         { id: 2, img: 'someOhterUrl'},         
       ]
      },
      { id: 2,
        title: 'Album Second',
        img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'
      },
      { id: 3,
        title: 'Album Second',
        img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg'
      }
    ];
```

}

I personally would have a state like this:

```
{
   albums: [
     {
       id: 1,
       title: 'Album First',  
       img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg',
       images: [      
         { id: 1, img: 'someUrl'},
         { id: 2, img: 'someOhterUrl'},         
       ]
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       title: 'Album Second',
       img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg',
       images: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Album Second',
      img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cb/9d/4a/cb9d4a0d055dd73eee404369e8cead2a.jpg',
      images: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice what I did ? Now it makes more sense, you have an array of `albums` and each album object has **the same structure and the same fields** which is crucial to keep consistency and avoid accessing fields that do not exist.

I updated the component but keep in mind that I would never access a specific item of an array, you should loop through each album and then use the AlbumShow component to display the relative info.

Comment: I pasted your edits to my code, but I still have error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Comment: I found another issue, let me add another edit, ahah sorry, we will figure this out together don't worry!

Comment: I hope! :) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!
Now I will try to loop through each album because it is challenge for me too :)

Comment: For example, I know that my "way" to id of album-element will be like this: album.albums['0'].id, but I don't know how i can do it with loop.

Comment: can we talk in chat? I have some questions and really need help ;(

Comment: Sure I might be slow to answer but yeah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145069/discussion-between-g4bri3l-and-valeria-shpiner).